# How to batch create GeoServer stores for each user?

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have  unix system with a number of regular users, each with his/her own database in PostGIS. I need to create a PostGIS store for each user.

I know how to do this in the web interface.

Is it possible to create the stores in a batch file/script instead of doing it one by one?

Comment: Read the documentation about REST. It might suit for you.