# How to batch create GeoServer users?

Tags: geoserver, batch, linux, geoserver-geofence, http

Is it possible to create GeoServer users for a list of usernames (and associated passwords) in one batch? (similar to [using the Linux `newusers` command](https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-create-multiple-users-accounts-in-batch.html) to create multiple users)

I've asked a related question about 
[How to batch create GeoServer stores for each user?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191833/how-to-batch-create-geoserver-stores-for-each-user). It seems that that's possible with the GeoServer RESTful API.

But how about the GeoServer users themselves?

Can I also batch create the users as well?

I searched about REST API for creating users/roles, but couldn't find anything.

---

I've tried the Geofence rest API as suggested: I deployed both `geoserver-2.8-SNAPSHOT-geofence-plugin.zip` and `geoserver-2.8-SNAPSHOT-geofence-server-plugin.zip`, rebooted, and when I used the REST API with

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -X POST -H "Content-type: text/xml" -d "<User> <username>testu</username> </User>" http://localhost/geoserver/rest/usergroup/users
```

, I got the following error, no user is added. Any ideas what I am doing wrong or any suggestions? (I can't change the system configuration files, so REST API is preferable.)

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'admin'
> POST /geoserver/rest/usergroup/users HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost
> Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-type: text/xml
> Content-Length: 41
> 
* upload completely sent off: 41 out of 41 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
< Date: Tue, 24 Jan 2017 04:57:58 GMT
< Server: Noelios-Restlet-Engine/1.0..8
< Allow: GET
< Content-Length: 0
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Comment: One possibility would be to use the geofence community module with http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/geofence-server/rest-userrole.html or maybe you could an alternative store (e.g. LDAP) and creating the users in that.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I'm aware, No. The GeoServer [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/2.8.3/user/webadmin/security/ugr.html) does not allude to the possibility, and only discusses single user creation.

Furthermore, when following OpenGeo Suite [tutorial](http://suite.opengeo.org/docs/latest/sysadmin/security/multiuser/index.html) on working on creating multiple users, they go through the process of showing how to create a user and then the following steps to create multiple users is the repeat the steps of creating a single user.

> Click Add new user again and repeat the above process, creating two new users, private_viewer and private_edit, and associating them with the ROLE_PRIVATE and ROLE_PRIVATEEDIT roles, respectively.

I've search for this capability as well to no avail in other forums, blogs etc...

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it via the web interface but you can do it by editing the users.xml file directly or using the rest API.

You can edit the file here:

> security/usergroup/{group-name}/users.xml

Or you can use the REST API:

> http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/geofence-server/rest-userrole.html

It's recommended that you use encrypted passwords, but to get the ball rolling you can use plain text passwords, e.g.

> plain:mypassword